# onmouseover issue -- original picture completely disappears

Tags: javascript, html, mouseover

My problem is that I'm not able to change picture based on different events, in my case, onmouseover. I'm using JavaScript and html5 standard.

Below is the affected html:

```
<img alt="" height="300" width="162" id="bronze" class="badges" src="bilder/Bronze160x310.png">
```

which is supposed to be reliant on the following piece:

```
<label class="block">
    <input name="Radio" type="radio" id="b1" onmouseover='updatePic("pictures/hi_again.png")' onchange="enableProceed(); updatePrice();" value="2.9">
    <span style="cursor:pointer">test</span>
</label>
```

I only have trouble with the onmouseover event. I haven't tested it thoroughly, but it seemed to work fine with onchange events.

The following is the JavaScript code:

```
function updatePic(newPic) {   
    document.getElementById("bronze").src = newPic; 
}
```

When I run this the original picture becomes unavailable even if I have not begun any mouseover. I used a switch-system for my JavaScript before, but the same problem occured.

Thanks in advance.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xfkjL3as/3/

Comment: are the images exist ? what does Developer Console tell ?

Comment: can you please make  jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have achieved what you are attempting to do in this JSFiddle.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/xfkjL3as/1/.

The **HTML** is as follows:

```
<img src="http://theunleashedreviewboard.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/angry-face.png" id="myImage">

<div>
    <input type="radio" id="myRadioButton" value="100" />
    <label for="myRadioButton">My Radio Button</label>
</div>
```

The **JavaScript** is as follows:

```
function updateImageSource(src)
{
    var myImage = document.getElementById("myImage");
    myImage.src = src;
}

var myRadioButton = document.getElementById("myRadioButton");

myRadioButton.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    updateImageSource('http://www.worldpeace-uk.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/smiley-face.jpg');
}, false);
```

I have used JavaScript to attach the `mouseover` event to the radiobutton HTML element.

---

**Sidenote:** It is generally a better practice to separate your JavaScript code from your HTML. While HTML provides you attributes such as `onmouseover` to achieve this, I would recommend to keep the JavaScript code in a separate file (and link it).

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739568/how-link-a-javascript-file-to-an-html-file) answers how to link a separate JavaScript file.

Comment: Thanks! It indeed seems to work. Moreover, I would like to ask you what I have done wrong and why your works. To my very uneducated eye, it looks as if you have only made it one step longer than necessary.

Comment: I have tried to add multiple eventlisteners to a group of radiobuttons using document.getElementByClassName(). It seems to work, but the function I have uses the radiobutton itself as argument, and I have realised that for each radiobutton the last inserted argument is used. So out of 5 radiobuttons, the 5:th has become the argument for each.

Comment: When I ran your JSFiddle, it comes up saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: updatePic is undefined`.