# How to use a bower package component into my project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, bower, angular-material, mean-stack

I am working on a mean stack application using angular material design. I got stuck on using 'md-datepicker'. I was designing a form which is having an Date of birth field but md-datepicker dont allow to select the year. I found a bower packer "https://github.com/alenaksu/mdPickers" and I was trying to add it into my project.

1. I installed the bower

   > npm install bower
2. Install package,

   > bower install mdpackages

after this steps I got the bower-components in my project directory. So my question is where should i link this components. (I am really new in the mean stack). Now I dont know how to use it in my project.
[image of the Dir of mdpicker-bower package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4faso.png)

I know the question is little bit confusing, but if some one can help me i am will open to teamviwer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you reference apropriate scripts/style in you index.html file, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739568/how-do-i-link-a-javascript-file-to-a-html-file or http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/448-how-do-you--use-bower_components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you instantiate your root application module, append `mdPickers` as a dependency.  Such as,

```
angular.module("app", [
    "mdPickers"
  ]);
```

In your controller, you then instantiate the component you want to use.

```
angular.module("app").controller("MainCtrl", ['$scope', '$mdpDatePicker', function($scope, $mdpDatePicker) {
  // do something with $mdpDatePicker
}]);
```

You can find more complete examples of how to use the module [here](http://codepen.io/alenaksu/pen/eNzbrZ).