# Magento 2: $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, themes, magento2

I added some js files in my custom theme using the file `\app\design\frontend\<vendor>\<theme>\Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml`

```
<link src="js/modernizr.custom.28468.js"/>
<link src="js/jquery.js"/>
<link src="js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
<link src="js/wow.js"/>
<link src="js/jquery.bxslider.js"/>
<link src="js/jquery_select.js"/>
<link src="js/page.js"/>
```

But it shows some errors in console, and functionality is not working properly

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLiCy.png)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that `modernizr...js` is probably dependent on jQuery. Thus jQuery must be referenced before it- I'm *sure* there's a duplicate, but I can't find a good one. Also using `<link>` for JS is an odd practice, `<script>` is more conventional: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739568/how-do-i-link-a-javascript-file-to-a-html-file

Comment: @HPierce Thanks for your reply. I have changed link to script and give order to jquery.js and modernizer..js. But still it is not working.

Answer (score 5):

This is because of some jquery conflicts in the js files you used.
Please add the below code in your first line of page.js

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
```