# Browser show blank page while using reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs

Hi I am new in reactjs when i am running server.js file from terminal it show blank page on browser. The code of index.html file is:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/babel-
core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
 <script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js">
</script>
 <script 
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-
  dom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
 <script type="text/babel">
   ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello React!</h1>,
   document.getElementById('app')
  );
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's in the file where you declare your <App> component?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I link a JavaScript file to a HTML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739568/how-do-i-link-a-javascript-file-to-a-html-file)

Comment: @Ben Chan I have only two file one is server.js and other one is index.html

Comment: You forgot to close the script tag...?

Comment: @AstenMies i close the tag but it still not working

Comment: What about <script src="URL"> instead of <script><src="URL> ?

Comment: @AstenMiles i have edit question but still it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working example.

In your code, the wrong part is the CDN link to babel-core. You may always check your console when working with JS (on Google Chrome: Ctrl + shift + J on Windows, Cmd + Opt + J on IOS).

On the other hand, I thought this was a good opportunity to also introduce components (see ).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>My First React Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="hello"></div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.0.0/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.0.0/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
      var Greeting = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
          return (
            <p>Hello World</p>
          )
        }
      });

      ReactDOM.render(
        <Greeting/>,
        document.getElementById('hello')
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: its working and i accept your answer. Can you tell me what is the issue in my code?

Comment: Hey @SundeepBadhotiya, I edited my answer, your CDN src was giving a 404...