# Using Javascript libaries such as Cheerio without node.js

Tags: javascript, libraries, cheerio

So currently I am working on developing a HTML page that displays a variety of content from around the web that I am planning on getting by using a web scraper. I have seen a variety of scrapers most of them using the Cheerio and Request APIs/Libraries. However all of these tutorials(such as:http://www.netinstructions.com/simple-web-scraping-with-node-js-and-javascript/ ) utilize Node.js rather than just a HTML file and .js files. I have no interest in using node.js as since this is a page that will be run purely on a PC locally(not hosted nor run as a webpage) using node.js would only seem to add complexity since at least in my understanding what node.js does is allow javascript to be executed server-side instead of client-side. So my question is how do I download and import libraries(such as: https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio )  into my main javascript file so that it can just be run via a browser?

Edit: Even if node.js is not just for server side my question stands. Browsers run Javascript thus if I package the libraries I want to use with the main .js and reference them it will work there without node.js. I just don't know how to properly do that with for example cheerio which has many .js files. 
Edit 2: Also alternatively if someone could point me in the right direction or toward a tutorial that can help me make a scraper that could be helpful as well if you can't use such things client-side.

Comment: I think your understanding of node.js is a little bit wrong. It is not used to execute code server side, it is used to execute javascript code. Express (which is a node.js library) is an example of a node.js server.

Comment: Here is one example of scrapping on the client: [link](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/client-side-web-scraping-with-javascript-using-jquery-and-regex-5b57a271cb86)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot import cheerio in the client as it is specifically made for nodejs. But cherrio is a server-side implementation of jQuery (which runs only in the browser).

To import jquery, you can it as a link in your html. For example :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You should place this file before importing your own javascript file.

Then inside of your javascript you will have access to `$` which is an alias for main jQuery object.

Here is a good example of what you could do : [How do I link a JavaScript file to a HTML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739568/how-do-i-link-a-javascript-file-to-a-html-file)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
looking for a similar solution found this :
[Github solution](https://github.com/oyyd/cheerio-without-node-native)
you just install the package with

```
npm i cheerio-without-node-native@0.20.2
```

and will be able to use cheerio without nodejs. Hope it helps.