# Using multiple <script> tag at the bottom of HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is that okay to have multiple Script tag at the bottom of HTML?
Here is the Script that I am using.

I was wondering if they will slow the speed?
or can cause any technical problem?

Is there any way that I can merge them into one file and linked it to my page? Or this might not be a good idea?

```
<script>
    $('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
    protect: true,
    infobar: true,
    idleTime: false,
    clickContent: false, 
    buttons: [
    //"zoom",
    //"share",
    //"slideShow",
    //"fullScreen",
    //"download",
    //"thumbs",
    "close"
    ],
    animationEffect: "fade",
    });
</script>    

<!-- Hamburger Menu -->
<script>
    var $menuham = $(".menuham");
        $menuham.on("click", function(e) {
            $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);
            $("h1.brandcolor").toggleClass("brandcolorw");
            $menuham.toggleClass("is-active");
    // Do something else, like open/close menu
    });
</script>
<!-- Project Info Button -->
<script>
  var $projectinfo = $(".projectinfo");
  $projectinfo.on("click", function(e) {
    $projectinfo.toggleClass("is-active");
    // Do something else, like open/close menu
  });
</script>    

<!-- Back to Top -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(window).scroll(function(){ 
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) { 
            $('#scroll').fadeIn(); 
        } else { 
            $('#scroll').fadeOut(); 
        } 
    }); 
    $('#scroll').click(function(){ 
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 250); 
        return false; 
    }); 
});
</script>  

<!-- Progress Bar -->
<script>
        // When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
    window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

    function myFunction() {
      var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
      var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
      document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i think it is okay to have multiple script tag. does your code have any problem?

Comment: Its completely fine and better than putting them inside `head` IMO.

Comment: [How do I link a Javascript file to a HTML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739568/how-do-i-link-a-javascript-file-to-a-html-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that okay to have multiple Script tag at the bottom of HTML? Here is the Script that I am using.

Yes thats where javascript should be. Either this, or at the top with **defer** atributte. Specially if you are performing operations on a loaded dom.

> I was wondering if they will slow the speed? or can cause any technical problem?

Nah, it wont be faster if you put them at the top. Though you can make it faster if you minify your js... if you are using some package manager like `npm` you can add some package to help you with this, if not there are tons of pages that can help you minify your code. just look on google: minify javascript... you can also minify css. **Edit:** actually it can look slower if you put them at the top and the files are to big. cause it starts loading content kind of asynchronously but in order, so depending on your internet connection, they might slow down the appearing of some content, nowadays is not too relevant.. unless you have reaally big js files.

> Is there any way that I can merge them into one file and linked it to my page? Or this might not be a good idea?

Yes just put your code together in one file, as long as the contents of the file are related its ok.

If you are building a site, put all the general code (the one that should be on all pages) on one file, that you can load on each page. And add at the bottom of each page the contents that are not general to the website but specific to that page.

I asume you are new to web development, this is good/works for learning, but eventually if you wanna work with javascript, i recommend investigating on package managers. But for now its ok.