# Notepad++ needs <script> ... </script> to execute functions when opening in firefox or chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I'm on day four of teaching my self. I have saved as my practice document as a .js JavaScript file, and selected "JavaScript" in the language drop down menu, however in contrast to the way I am learning JavaScript on scrimba.com the only way my JavaScript code will run is if I surround all separate functions with `<script> ... </script>` and that seems more like HTML than JavaScript.

I have tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> in chrome and paste my code, but I can't see any output. I have tried copying and pasting the saved JavaScript file that i made in Notepad++ with google chrome.

```
<script>
alert("javascript is running");
</script>

<script>
var myStr= "This is the start." + " This is the end.";
</script>
<script>
document.write(myStr);
</script>
```

I suspect my code should be cleaner than what I provided, with less karats, however at the moment my code pops up as plain text in all scenarios that don't include the `<script> ... </script>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I link a JavaScript file to a HTML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739568/how-do-i-link-a-javascript-file-to-a-html-file)

Comment: Your JavaScript needs to run in a browser; create an HTML file that contains a `<script src="your.js"></script>` element & save it in the same directory as your .js file.  Remove the `<script>` tags from your .js file & when you open/refresh the HTML file your script will run.