# Accessing GeoFirestore Utility Functions (calculateDistance)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I'm new to web development. I am writing a javascript webapp and am unclear on the syntax to access GeoFirestore's **calculateDistance** utility function and get the error **ReferenceError: calculateDistance is not defined**. This function is located in the **utils.ts** TypeScript file, but somehow I'm not picking it up.

I've tried various syntaxes to call the "calculateDistance" function as well as trying various  paths.

I thought pulling the full geofirestore.js library would be sufficient to pull in the utils functions.

[Utils.ts documentation is here](https://geofirestore.com/modules/_utils_.html).

My index.html file snippet:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/geofirestore/dist/geofirestore.js"></script>
```

My Javascript module snippet:

```
let geopoint1 = new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(40.123, -120.456)
let geopoint2 = new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(-20.456, 100.123)
console.log("Distance: " + calculateDistance(geopoint1,geopoint2).toString() + " km")
```

I get the following error. 
"ReferenceError: calculateDistance is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

The `calculateDistance` function is not exported outside of the library (aka it's not made for you to use). However as the maintainer of geofirestore I'd recommend you trying out my library geokit which provides a distance calculation method => https://github.com/MichaelSolati/geokit#geokitdistancestart-latlngliteral-end-latlngliteral-unit-string-number

Answer (score -1):

Your syntax for using the ‘calculateDistance’ function is correct. The only error here is that your Javascript cannot find the ‘calculateDistance’ function. Try downloading the geofirestore project [here](https://github.com/geofirestore/geofirestore-js/tree/aa80c713e321cb9ee1b8c62ffa90660a8f1a14ff) and running your code locally. Your error could also be occurring because of where you are putting your  tags. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739568/how-do-i-link-a-javascript-file-to-a-html-file) link will be helpful figuring out where to put your  tags for external libraries.