# How to include CDN in HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, datatable, datatables

I am using DataTables for a project and want to include this CDN provided (picture below).
[image]

How do I add this to my HTML file? Do I have to add this CDN link between  somewhere in my HTML file? It does not seem to be working correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I link a JavaScript file to a HTML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739568/how-do-i-link-a-javascript-file-to-a-html-file)

Comment: Side note: In the above CDN example, the URL starts with `//cdn.datatables.net...`. But this protocol-relative URL should [no longer be used](https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/). The URL examples in the answers to this question (which start with `https:`) are more appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

You can add cdn like this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/sorting/enum.js"></script>
```

or you can create a custom js file in which you can paste all code of this file and
then save it in whatever the folder you want and then link it
for example:-

```
<script src="js/enum.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A CDN is a content delivery network: https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/cdn/what-is-a-cdn/
you can add it in the end of the body tag

```js
<script src="the cdn"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add it at the very top of your HTML code in this format

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`src=` points to the CDN file ...there are different CDN directories and some are more stable than others so be careful where it's hosted