# vite-RollupError: Could not resolve

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, vite

Please help me with this error I am encountering while running `npm run build` for a simple portfolio website I am creating using HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and Vite. The error message I receive is as follows:

```
RollupError: Could not resolve "./src/main.js" from "index.html"
```

I have Node installed, and I'm not sure what is causing this error. Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I link a JavaScript file to a HTML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739568/how-do-i-link-a-javascript-file-to-a-html-file)